# Change different object's stylesheet Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

How to change the stylesheet of a different object? Essentially, when I hover over an object, I want it to change a different object's stylesheet (in this case the background colour).

**Entire XML Code for UI:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>addClan</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="addClan">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1070</width>
    <height>720</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="background_image">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-10</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>1081</width>
      <height>741</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-image: url(:/addClan/background image.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="clans_list">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>861</width>
      <height>401</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QGroupBox#clans_list{
border: 2px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="saved_clan_0">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>1</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>859</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QGroupBox{
border: 1px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}

QGroupBox:hover{
    background-color: red;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>5</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>68</width>
        <height>68</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="mouseTracking">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>18</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
        <pointsize>18</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>1</y>
        <width>857</width>
        <height>78</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame {
background-color: white;
}

QFrame:hover {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <zorder>frame_0</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_name_0</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_shield_0</zorder>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="saved_clan_1">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>1</x>
       <y>80</y>
       <width>859</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QGroupBox{
border: 1px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield_1">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>5</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>68</width>
        <height>68</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name_1">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>18</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
        <pointsize>18</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_1">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>1</y>
        <width>857</width>
        <height>78</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame {
background-color: white;
}

QFrame:hover {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <zorder>frame_1</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_name_1</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_shield_1</zorder>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="saved_clan_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>1</x>
       <y>160</y>
       <width>859</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QGroupBox{
border: 1px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>5</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>68</width>
        <height>68</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>18</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
        <pointsize>18</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>1</y>
        <width>857</width>
        <height>78</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame {
background-color: white;
}

QFrame:hover {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <zorder>frame_2</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_name_2</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_shield_2</zorder>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="saved_clan_3">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>1</x>
       <y>240</y>
       <width>859</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QGroupBox{
border: 1px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>5</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>68</width>
        <height>68</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>18</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
        <pointsize>18</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>1</y>
        <width>857</width>
        <height>78</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame {
background-color: white;
}

QFrame:hover {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <zorder>frame_3</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_name_3</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_shield_3</zorder>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="saved_clan_4">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>1</x>
       <y>320</y>
       <width>859</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QGroupBox{
border: 1px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
background-color: white;
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>5</x>
        <y>6</y>
        <width>68</width>
        <height>68</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="scaledContents">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>18</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
        <pointsize>18</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>1</y>
        <width>857</width>
        <height>78</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame {
background-color: white;
}

QFrame:hover {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <zorder>frame_4</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_name_4</zorder>
     <zorder>clan_shield_4</zorder>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="add_clan_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>109</x>
      <y>520</y>
      <width>861</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0511364, y1:0.5, x2:0.938, y2:0.534091, stop:0 rgba(231, 163, 4, 255), stop:1 rgba(238, 211, 4, 255));
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10; 
    padding: 6; 
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 1;
    border-top-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-left-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    border-style: outset;
    border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>ADD NEW CLAN</string>
    </property>
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="checked">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="default">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="add_clan_group">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>631</width>
      <height>301</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QGroupBox {
border: 2px solid gray;
border-color: #424242;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: white
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_tag_label">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>10</y>
       <width>191</width>
       <height>51</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
       <pointsize>16</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Clan Tag</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="clan_entry">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>60</y>
       <width>461</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Calibri</family>
       <pointsize>18</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
border-radius: 7;
border: 1px solid black</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>#</string>
     </property>
     <property name="placeholderText">
      <string>#</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="search_clan_button">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>490</x>
       <y>60</y>
       <width>121</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <italic>false</italic>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="autoFillBackground">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0511364, y1:0.5, x2:0.938, y2:0.534091, stop:0 rgba(231, 163, 4, 255), stop:1 rgba(238, 211, 4, 255));
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10; 
    padding: 6; 
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 1;
    border-top-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-left-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    border-style: outset;
    border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>SEARCH</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="default">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="flat">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_shield">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>110</y>
       <width>120</width>
       <height>120</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true"/>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="clan_name">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>140</x>
       <y>110</y>
       <width>221</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QTextEdit" name="clan_description">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>140</x>
       <y>155</y>
       <width>471</width>
       <height>65</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Calibri</family>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>50</weight>
       <bold>false</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
border-radius: 7;
border: 1px solid black</string>
     </property>
     <property name="readOnly">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="no_clan">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>100</y>
       <width>371</width>
       <height>31</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Calibri</family>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color: red</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>No clan found! Please try again.</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="confirm_clan">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>230</y>
       <width>591</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Supercell-Magic</family>
       <pointsize>14</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <italic>false</italic>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="autoFillBackground">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.125, y1:0.466, x2:0.938, y2:0.472, stop:0 rgba(0, 144, 24, 255), stop:1 rgba(124, 255, 38, 255));
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10; 
    padding: 6; 
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 1;
    border-top-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-left-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    border-style: outset;
    border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);
    
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>CONFIRM SELECTION</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="default">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="flat">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1070</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="Game Graphics/source.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

To clarify, I want to make it so hovering over clan_shield_0 changes the background colour of frame_0. I know that hovering over frame_0 already changes its background colour, but I need clan_shield_0 to change frame_0's background colour too.

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you show an example ([mre]) of the objects you are talking about

Comment: An image is not an MRE, it provides the .ui and everything you need (.py, .h or .cpp). Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: The only other thing I could send you is the stylesheet edit window which is currently blank. Literally, there is no code, I just want to know if it's possible for this to work.

Comment: In theory, it would be something like

QLabel#example_object:hover {

*code to edit the frame's background colour (if possible)*

}

Comment: Everything generates code, the .ui is XML code, open it with any editor and copy the content in the post. In theory everything is possible but practice limits a lot. Please read the links

Comment: Sorry for getting frustrated, been a long day lmao. Updated to include the XML code

Comment: I think that it is not possible only with QtDesigner so my question is: are you using [tag:python] or [tag:C++] or another technology?

Comment: I'm using python

Comment: @SamLeighton , I didn't understand what you want, could you explain it by simple UI, If you understand in the simple example you can extend it any where you want